# TCP_NO_DELAY setting not applied in CentOS 5.5

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am deploying a socket application in C++ on both CentOS 5.5 32 bit and CentOS 6.7 64 bit. I need to turn of Nagle's Algorithm as I am communication with an instrument and need as low of latency as possible. The code that I am using to turn off Nagle's Algorithm is below.

```
if (!setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&val, sizeof(val)))
        return SUCCESS;
    else
        return TRANSPORT_ERROR;
```

For the CentOS 5.5 system it seems that Nagle's algorithm is not being disabled. I can see in wireshark traces that several of the TCP writes in my application are being bundled together in one packet after about a 200ms delay.

The entire application in CentOS 6.7 runs in under 25ms. It is my understand that the only way packets would be bundled together like this is Nagle's Algorithm. Is this accurate, or is there something that I am missing?

Any help that anyone can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered printing `errno`? Without that information your question is a waste of time.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. There is not an error detected. The setsocketopt call returns successfully. I can even verify with getsockopt that the TCP driver thinks that Nagle's algorithm is turned off. However, I am seeing behavior in CentOS that seems to indicate that it is not being turned off correctly.

Comment: If you want low latency do not use TCP/IP. TCP reserves the right to bundle data together as it sees fit. There are also things like congestion control over which you have no control that can inject painful amounts of delay. Consider using UDP with a handshake. If the receiver doesn't ACK the message within a time period that is totally within your control, resend the packet.